# Send email via contact form using php post at most basic level

Tags: php

I am trying to learn how to send email from a contact form using phpmail and post. I must include the 'from' field for the phpmail function to work on my server. I want to do this at the most basic level to help learn and add in things like striptags sanistising functions etc later, so far I have this code but it's not working so far, any ideas and help much appreciated, Emma :)

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="send.php" method="post">
 First name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br><br>
 Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br><br>
 E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

And the php is this:

```
<?php

$email_message = ($_POST['firstname'],);
$email_subject  = ($_POST['lastname'],);
$email = ($_POST['email']);

$email_to = "emmajane1@hotmail.co.uk"; // your email address send TO
$email_from = "admin@emmajane.website"; // your email address send FROM
$email_subject = "Contact form message"; 




/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email, $email_message, $headers);  


?>
```

I don't see a button to answer my own question, but at the most basic level I got it working with this script below, now I'm going to build the php script up layer by layer till I get to where I want.

```
<?php


 $to      = 'emmajane@hotmail.co.uk';
 $subject = 'the subject';

 $headers = 'admin@emmajane.website';

 $message = $_POST['firstname']; 


 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 ?>
```

Comment: `firstname` is not equal to `firstName` so as `lastname` and `lastName`

Comment: *How* is it not working? What is happening?

Comment: Looks like you've not set any `$headers`, too

Comment: Masivuye, thanks I Have equaled out firstname and lastname.

Comment: John the email is not getting sent through from the contact form, so I'm wondering if my php script is incorrect somehow.